# How do I lock a pipeline in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Say I've got that pipeline building my stuff.

I'm polling my Git repo every 15 minutes for changes. The whole build might take more than these 15 minutes.

Is there any way to tell the pipeline not to start when a build is already running?

Comment: Do you mean jobs?
It should looks like:
Settings -Extended Setting - Block Build, when project builds

Comment: No, that's for Jobs. The question is about Pipelines, which have a very different configuration page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself: on the `General` tab of the job configuration, there's `Do not allow concurrent builds`